# Make a struct returned by ethers.js writable?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethers.js

In my smart contract, I keep some contract metadata in a struct called _data.  What I want to build is a mechanism to retrieve this metadata, make required changes, and then write the struct back to the contract.

Problem is that, on the client side, ethers.js returns a Solidty struct as array of values conjoined with an object that looks like the struct.  I can coerce the the return value into an object, but unfortunately its properties seem to be unwritable. I receive a compile error "Cannot assign to readonly property [name] of object '[object Array']

Sample code below:

What I want to do be able to do when I want to make a change to this metadata is something like>

Soldity:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.6;

struct Person {
       string name;
       uint8 age;
}
    
contract PersonContract {
      Person private  _data;
      
      function getPerson() public view returns(Person memory) {
         return _data;
      }
      function setPerson(Person memory person_) public {
         _data = person_;
      }
}
```

Client-side:  (Ethers.js/Typescript}

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { PersonContract } from "../typechain/PersonContract";

interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
describe.only('Person', () => {
    let person: PersonContract;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        let fact = await ethers.getContractFactory("PersonContract");
        person = await fact.deploy();
    });

    it('gets a person', async () => {
        let myPerson = <Person>{};
        myPerson.name = "John";
        myPerson.age = 30;
        await person.setPerson(myPerson);
        let personFromContract : Person = await person.getPerson();
        console.log(personFromContract);
        personFromContract.name="Peter";  <==Produces runtime error
        console.log(personFromContract);
    })
})
```

Running the test produces the error  `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '[object Array]'`

Is there a quick way to make `myPerson` writable, so I can modify it and write it back to the smart contract?

Comment: Can you show the output of console.log(myPerson) ?

Comment: ['John', 30, name: 'John', age: 30 ].   It returns both the array members and object keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late but for anyone else coming across this question ...

I believe the issue is that the object is immutable, so you'd have to make a copy of the object and change that.

This is typically done using the "spread" operator, which is the three dots (...) that basically makes a shallow copy of the object that is mutable.

```
    const result: Person = await person.getPerson();
    let personFromContract = { ...result };
    personFromContract.name="Peter";  <== Should be okay now
```

I made result a const just to reinforce that it is immutable and it's good practict anyway.

You can also shorten it a bit like so:

```
    const result: Person = await person.getPerson();
    let personFromContract = { ...result, name: "Peter" };
```

Hope this helps folks wandering into this question.